# Using Lagrange multiplier to find eigenvector for the minimum eigenvalue in a symmetric matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

Without the usage of Spectral theorem, with $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} \bullet A \mathbf{x}$ and $g(\mathbf{x}) = |\mathbf{x}|^2 -1$ and $A$ is a symmetric $n{\times}n$ matrix, I used Lagrange multiplier to try to prove that for any $\mathbf{y}$ that is a solution satisfying the multiplier, then $A\mathbf{y} = \lambda_1\mathbf{y}$ where $\lambda_1 := \min_{|\mathbf{x}|=1}\mathbf{x}\bullet A\mathbf{x}$.

However, I'm stuck after simplifying the equations in Lagrange to narrow it down to: $$2A\mathbf{x} + 2\lambda_1\mathbf{x} = 0$$ $$|\mathbf{x}|^2=1$$
Can anyone tell me if there are steps that I did wrong, and if there are any hints moving forward to find the solution?

Comment: How are $A$ and $Q$ related? Is $Q = A$?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming that $A$ and $Q$ are the same matrix here...)

Well, you could divide the first equation by two and move the second term to the other side, getting

$$
Ax = -\lambda_1 x
$$
which should *not* have a minus-sign, and suggests you made a computational error earlier.

But also: there are multiple solutions to the lagrange multiplier problem: both the eigenvectors for the min and the max eigenvalues, for instance. (Unless you're also checking second derivatives, of course.)

You might want to work through the case
$$
A = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & -3}
$$
and see where your argument goes wrong.

Comment: I went through the example you gave me, which got me to the Lagrange of: $$4x_1=-\lambda 2x_1$$ $$-6x_2 = -\lambda 2x_2$$ So, the minus sign will only cancel out if $a_{ii}$ has a negative sign, does that mean that $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda\mathbf{x}$ varies depending on the diagonal value of $A$?

Comment: @JohnnyYang Looks to me like you used $f+\lambda g$ instead of $f-\lambda g$ when you set up the Lagrange multiplier problem.

Comment: @amd I thought when we are dealing with Lagrange for constrained optimization, $f+\lambda g$ would be the correct equation. Is that wrong?

Comment: @JohnnyYang Either way works, since the change of sign just negates the values of the multipliers. Here, if you start with $f-\lambda g$, the values of $\lambda$ that solve the constrained problem will turn out the be exactly the eigenvalues of $A$, which is what you’re after, instead of their negatives.

Comment: @amd I don't really understand what you mean by "the change of sign [will] just negat[e] the values of the multipliers". What would be the definition of the multiplier? Since it's possible that $g(\mathbf{x})$ and $\lambda$ are either negative or positive, how would we negate the sign change?

Comment: @JohnnyYang The solutions of $\nabla(f-\lambda g)=0$ and $\nabla(f+\lambda g)=0$ differ only in the sign of their values for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $\langle x,Ax\rangle-\lambda(\langle x,x\rangle-1)$ in $v$ is
$$\langle v,Ax\rangle+\langle x,Av\rangle-\lambda\cdot2\langle x,v\rangle.$$
Using the symmetry of $A$ it's equal to 
$$2\langle Ax,v\rangle+2\langle -\lambda x,v\rangle
=2\langle Ax-\lambda x,v\rangle.$$
That equals zero if $Ax=\lambda x$ and we have 
$$\langle x,Ax\rangle =\langle x,\lambda x\rangle=\lambda\langle x,x\rangle=\lambda\cdot1.$$